# Bound mismatch: The type is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter

Tags: java, oop, generics

I've recently started implementing a few data structures and, well, I am trying to make everything as 'extensible' as possible.

```
public abstract class AbstractNode<E extends Element, U extends AbstractNode<E, U>> { ... }

public class BinarySearchTree<Element> extends Tree<Element, Node<Element>> { ... }

public class Element implements Cloneable { ... }

public class Node<E extends Element> extends AbstractNode<E, Node<E>> { ... }

public abstract class Tree<E extends Element, T extends AbstractNode<E, T>> { ... }
```

I am getting a lot of errors in the `BinarySearchTree` class with the message `Bound mismatch: The type Element is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <E extends Element> of the type Node<E>`. Why!? What am I doing wrong there?

Also, in the BinarySearchTree class I am getting a `The type parameter Element is hiding the type Element` right in `BinarySearchTree<Element>`.

Ty for the help!

Comment: Code, please? We need to see the actual code where errors happen, together with the exact location of the error as reported by the compiler.

Comment: I did post the whole code here https://gist.github.com/Alex-Cosma/3378f475adb78a42c2c0

Comment: @Alexandr, I extracted the code, needed to understand the issue. :)

Comment: Yes, I saw that, thank you, however the innards of these classes may also be important

Comment: How about posting the lines that compiler complains about?

Comment: `public class BinarySearchTree<T extends Element> extends Tree<T, Node<T>> {

 public void generateStaticBinarySearchTree() {

  root = new Node<Element>(null, new Element(15));

 }
}`
I get a `Type mismatch: cannot convert from Node<Element> to Node<T>`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The definition of your `BinarySearchTree` is:

```
public class BinarySearchTree<Element> extends Tree<Element, Node<Element>>
```

Here, `Element` is a type-parameter, but not the actual type `Element`. It's pretty much the same, as you did:

```
public class BinarySearchTree<T> extends Tree<T, Node<T>>
```

Now the error you're getting makes more sense:

> The type `T` is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter `<T extends Element>` of the type `Node<T>`

This is reasonable, because the parameter `T` doesn't have an upper bound `Element`, which is required by the definition of `Node`. This can be easily fixed with:

```
public class BinarySearchTree<T extends Element> extends Tree<T, Node<T>>
```

Note that here, the upper-bound is not a type-parameter, but an actual type (`Element`).

As a rule of thumb, you should avoid naming your type-parameters like existing types, because a lot of confusion can happen. The type-parameters names usually consist of a single, upper-cased letter. If you follow this practice, it would be very, very difficult to end up with similar issues.

Comment: And what if in the Tree class, I had a `protected T root;` and I would want to initialize it in the `BinarySearchTree` class without any casting? I cannot write `root = new Node<Element>(null, new Element(15));`..